# How can I heal in battle?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I've noticed that I tend to take a lot of damage, and especially that once I take one hit I'm prone to take a couple more in succession.  This makes the cost of a single mistake rather harsh.

Is there any way to heal *during* battle?

Comment: Abuse the dodge-roll. (spacebar) Not even kidding. I about halved my deaths per minute once I realized the effectiveness of it.

Comment: Yeap. Can't stress the importance of dodge-rolling more..

Comment: on dark mode, you have access to a special vampiric armor/weapon set that leeches vitality from enemies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can enhance your vitality regen with potions, mutagens and talents. There is however no such thing as a health potion.

Answer (score 12):

You can only drink potions before battle, never during battle. This means the only way is to increase your vitality regeneration during combat. There are several ways to do that:

- Swallow potion (+1 vitality regeneration in combat)
- Gadwall potion (+2 vitality regeneration in combat, but -40% damage)
- Visit a Place of Power for Vitality

Comment: In the battle with the kayran i was able to drink potions during the battle. I'm not sure what other battles this applies to as i'm not very far in the story but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should drink Swallow potion before going into tough battles. It will boost your health regeneration.

Comment: Swallow is not the only potion to boost health regen.

Answer (score 1):

You can drink a Gadwall & Swallow before combat. Also if you have the catalysis skill from the alchemy skill tree the vitality regenerations is improved further and the potions negative effects(gadwall only) are reduced significantly. There are also items and mutagens that increase vitality regeneration although I'm not certain if they do it in combat.

Answer (score 0):

run away from your enemies your health will regenerate slowly

Comment: Only when you have vitality regeneration during combat, else you can run all you want it is not going to heal you.